# Broken Wayland login

Tags: wayland

Before yesterday, I install Ubuntu 19.10. It has both X11 and Wayland on login option. I choose Ubuntu on Wayland, I like it. But today it forces login only with X11 and lose the Wayland option. I don't understand what happen.

Could I get/reinstall Ubuntu With Wayland back?

Comment: Read [the wiki post](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland) and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069292/how-can-i-get-the-ubuntu-with-wayland-option-on-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a NVIDIA GPU, 19.10 will not allow you to login in Wayland.

I know because I just checked that.

I was able to do it in 19.04, but in 19.10 I cannot. Some change were made for 19.10 that makes something incompatible with Nvidia cards, till their drives are updated.

If you change to the nouveau drivers, I think it will let you choose Wayland.